# what is the equivalent of System.currenttimemilliseconds in NDK?

Tags: android, c++, c, time, android-ndk

I want to measure times in my application at the NDK level. I would preferably like to do it the Java way with milliseconds granularity. In Java, a simple call to

> System.currentTimeMilliseconds()

does the trick. Is there an exact duplicate call in NDK, or will we need to use time.h and do calculations the standard C way?

Comment: I believe `time(0)` will return the same value (it's declared in time.h).

Comment: let me try these, guess that's the only way right now